# Vim Highlight Trailing Whitespace AND Spaces Before and After Tabs

Tags: tabs, vim, spaces, trailing

I got this from the vim wiki and added it to my .vimrc to highlight trailing whitespace, and spaces before tabs (only when in insert mode):

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace guibg=purple
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$%#\@<!$\| \+\ze\t/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

I would like to extend this to include spaces after tabs.

So, I would like to:

1. Highlight all trailing whitespace.
2. Highlight spaces before, and after tabs.
3. Don't highlight trailing whitespace while I am typing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mention it at all have you tried using listchars? I have this in my .vimrc it doesn't highlight them but you can pick any special characters you want to show for them:

```
set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:·,extends:>,precedes:<
```